# Trying to get property 'name' of non-object?

Tags: laravel

Hi Guys i am new to laravel and i am trying to retrieve category names for each formation and i am getting this error

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (0)

The "name" i am trying to retrieve is the name of category that my formation belongs to.

*This is My Category Model*

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    function formations()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Formation');
        }

    protected $fillable =['name','description'];
}
```

*And This is My Formation Model*

```
class Formation extends Model
{
   function category()
       {
           return $this->belongsTo('App\Category',"category_id");
       }
   protected $fillable =['name','price','durations','category_id'];
}
```

*And here is my view page where i am trying to retrieve the category name*

```
@foreach($formations as $formation)

        <td>{{$formation->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$formation->price}}</td>
        <td>{{$formation->category->name}}</td>
        td>{{$formation->durations}}</td>

@endforeach
```

*This is My Controller*

```
    public function index()
{
    //$formations = Formation::all();
    $formations = Formation::with('category')->paginate('4');
    $categories = Category::all();
    return view('formation.index',compact('categories','formations'));
}
```

Any Suggestion about where i might be wrong ? And thanks in Advance !

Comment: Can you add foreign key and local key to the relationship and try...

Comment: like `$this->belongsTo('App\Category',"category_id","category_id");`

Comment: for being sure that your relation functions in model are correct or not, you can test them in controller, like this in your controller: `dd($formations[0]->category);` , if this shows you a collection from category so this is ok else your relations method is not ok

Comment: @Rezash That's didn't work for me

Comment: @MohamedMidou so your relation methods are incorrect, read this https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: `dd($formations)` in your controller and show us the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually comes when you have removed one or more row from database, but trying to access that row with an `id`. Make sure that you have all the category in the `category` table with the `id` which is mentioned in the `formation` table `category_id` field.

Comment: that's exactly the problem i have deleted one row from database and i forgot that, silly me thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the relationship

```
class Formation extends Model
{
function category()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Category',"id","category_id"); //if your categories id is id
   }
protected $fillable =['name','price','durations','category_id'];
}
```

In your view

```
  @foreach($formations as $formation)

    <td>{{$formation->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$formation->price}}</td>
    <td>{{$formation->category->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$formation->durations}}</td>

  @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view

```
@foreach($formations as $formation)
 <td>{{$formation->name}}</td>
 <td>{{$formation->price}}</td>
 <td> {{ $formation->categories()->pluck('name')->implode(' ') }}</td>
 <td>{{$formation->durations}}</td>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was that i have deleted a row from my category table in database that's why the name wasn't recognized.